# SQL query filtering on COUNT of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to filter a SQL query based on a count of records within that query.

I want the query to return only the rows where the count of "Location" is greater than 5.

For example, we have 100 rows of data.  10 "Locations" make up all 100 rows, but I only want the rows where the `COUNT("Location") > 5`, essentially eliminating the rows with Locations where the `COUNT("Location") < 5`.

I've tried combinations of aggregation and the `HAVING` clause but can't nail down the answer.

Comment: HAVING should do it. Please put an example data and query on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by location) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 5;
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer from Gordon Linoff using CTE:

```
with CTE as(
select *, count(*) over (partition by Location) as count from table 
)

select *from CTE where count >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you may have been after by using the HAVING clause...

```
select t.*
from t
inner join
(
    select Location, count(*) as Count
    from t
    group by Location
    having count(*) >= 5
) as t2 on t.Location = t2.Location
order by t.ID
```

Here it is in [action](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1c08ca39dc443d282f0b5dd8f371056).